# Java Downward compatibility clarification

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

I need a little clarification regarding JRE. Is it downward compatible? I mean if I develop an application using java5 and if the target has the latest java6 will my application be able to run?

Comment: I think that is the reverse of "downward" compatible

Comment: @matt: the author is correct with terms, because [downward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility)==backward and JRE is backward compatible. See also related SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible).

Answer (score 6):

unless you are using the incompatibilities listed in sun documents [Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided you're not using ***really*** old deprecated APIs (like, ones deprecated in v1.1)...and maybe even then.

That's APIs. The *bytecode* is absolutely forward-compatible. It's been revised a couple of times, but always in a forward-compatible way. So code compiled with JDK 1.4 runs fine in the latest; but code compiled with the latest may not run with an older JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Java's very good about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing about it here [java backwards compatibility](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-8-backwards-compatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

The bytecodes generated can be run in future releases of `jvm` however the compiler is not backward compatible as bytecodes generated with higher version won't run in older version. This is a good read on Sun site [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)