# old jre 1.3 on windows 8

Tags: windows, java, backwards-compatibility

We have a very old client-server application that uses JRE 1.3, it's network communication is based on sockets and has a desktop client, my boss is asking me to investigate the chance to install it on windows 8.
I don´t have a windows 8 at hand, so has someone tried to do such thing?
The desktop app is really huge, so upgrading it, is not an option.

Comment: How about getting the redistributable ZIP version of JRE and using it explicitly from command line?

Comment: Is the application not working properly on JRE 1.6+? I thought JRE is backward compatible... Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible

Comment: it should not be a problem AFAIK. But not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strives to keep very strict backwards compatibility, so I would try to install the latest Oracle Java JRE version on the Windows 8 machine and execute the application on that.

Chances are it will work out of the box.

Comment: Forgot to say that it uses jnlp for deploying.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrea says in another answer, backwards compatibility is very important in Java. However things do get deprecated and potentially eventually removed.

You may want to review the following, lists of things deprecated in the various java versions in case something in there is core to how your application works.

- Java 7:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html
- Java 6:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/deprecated-list.html
- Java 5:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/deprecated-list.html
- Java 4:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Anyway i will have to test, thanks for the info!