# Java JComboBox Generics

Tags: java, swing, generics, jcombobox, type-erasure

recently I have been reading somewhat more about Java Generics and came to this article: http://gafter.blogspot.nl/2004/09/puzzling-through-erasure-answer.html, which basically says that Java will always be backwards compatible.

Now, what has Java done to JComboBox? Code written in Java 7, ie. `JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();` should compile just fine in Java 6, but then as a raw type as the type has been erased.

However as you can easily see when googling this, there are three different issues now:

- First of all, Java 6 does not compile on Generics, while it should do so with type erasure and treat it as a raw type.
- Secondly, not even reification is being used, so nothing is gained in Java 7.
- And thirdly, Java 7 code that uses raw types gives warnings.

So there does not seem to be a correct way.

Regards.

Comment: Well, the diamond operator is introduced in Java 7, so I'm not sure why you say: it should compile just fine in Java 6. Cause it won't.

Comment: @ErikPragt I might have thought the other way around... So I thought the wrong way around?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4692743/604478. If you want compile for older version, you have to use the `-target` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a language target level and a bytecode target level. This way you can use all the language feature of a certain version and compile it against a specific vm version. I tested your example with the following setting: Language level 7, bytecode version 6 and it compiles just fine.

But you still would have to compile it against a jdk 7, so the compiler knows that the JCombobox is generic.