# Android and Eclipse: minSdk and compileWith

Tags: android

Well, I think that is not well explained and right now I'm a little bit confused. From [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) link:

> **Compile With** is the platform version against which you will compile
>   your app. By default, **this is set to the latest version of Android
>   available in your SDK**. (It should be Android 4.1 or greater; if you
>   don't have such a version available, you must install one using the
>   SDK Manager). **You can still build your app to support older versions**,
>   but setting the build target to the latest version allows you to
>   enable new features and optimize your app for a great user experience
>   on the latest devices.

From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#platform) one  instead:

> When you are developing your application, you will need to choose the
>   platform version against which you will compile the application. In
>   general, **you should compile your application against the lowest
>   possible version of the platform that your application can support**.

Now, as they are contradicting themselves, here I'll explain what I've understood: let's say that we compile with api 5. It means that if I run from 1 to 5, my application works but it doesn't for versions > 5. So:

1. Why I need to set the minSdkVersion if compileWith is set to 5?
2. What is targetSdkVersion?

The point is: if compileWith is set to the latest version, is it possible to use latest APIs and still have backward compatibility? I'm sure that I'm wrong and I'm missing something. Thank you.

**Edit 1**

Now I understand more but anyway I'm missing something: let's say that minSdk is 9 and target is 18 (my current sdk). It means that I cannot use anything specific to api 18 unless there's some support package for older versions, right? I'm thinking different: I would compile with the lowest version possible to get forward compatibility. I mean, if you compile a Windows application on Win2000, it will run till Windows 8 but I'm limited to Win2000 apis. If I compile with Windows 8, the backward compatibility should be checked on runtime and I can use Windows 8 apis on Win2000 only with "support packages" (it's an example, obviously). Right?

**Edit 2**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible) is what I'm asking about Android (not about the JVM). Android is mixing forward with backward and I've mixed it more using the Windows example. FIY, It seems that Windows is backward compatible, as explained in the examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29). So, what about Android? It seems that the minSdk version should be tested from the developer, I mean: I should compile with latest version and test my application behaviour till the minimum api level that doesn't change it. So it seems that I need to test the backward compatibility by testing on every api level lower than the one with wich is compiled and they assure the forward compatibility. Right?

I think that I'm mixing forward and backward compatibility definitions. Everytime I read them they seem different.

Comment: did my new update anwered your question ? if so, please mark it as correct so that other people with the same question can see it clearly. thank you.

Comment: clear, but not enough, read my updates!

Comment: i hope now you have what you are looking for.

Comment: has my solution solved your confusion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) you can read the following:

**android:minSdkVersion**

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system **will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower** than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

and

**android:targetSdkVersion**

An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.
This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system **should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.** The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

And to answer your last question, targeting the latest API will not allow you to execute any newer method or use any newer class on old phones, for that you need to use the support packages, with that you are able to obtain a close result to what you can do in newer APIs.

Hope this gives you a more clear idead of why you have those two values and the difference between them.

**UPDATE:**

Well about the example of something built for windows 2000 and working on windows 8, is not guarantee that it will work, that is why on windows you have the "run with compatibility" mode, and then you select according to what operating system you want to run it.

This is because maybe both OS (or APIs in this case) have the same method or option, they do it in a different ways or need other permissions. The same happens here, so the target SDK will be the reference frame against you tested and thus it will use that behavior  if you run it on newer devides than the taget SDK.

For the APIs between the min and the target they will run as normally they do, and so you can always have a weird behavior and some patching might be need it, normally is most visible on the 2.x to 3.x jump.

**UPDATE 2:**

Well, let me try to explain it in a different way.

The minSDK will determine which methods and options you can use throughout the application, this means that if a method is only available after that API, you will not be able to use it and instead get an error message.

The targetSDK represents the lastest version of the API that you tested and so, if the phone has a newer API than the one you specified, it will try to behave as it was on the API version you specified, take for example [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html), in the section **Important Behavior Changes**:

> This inexact batching behavior applies only to updated apps. If you've set the targetSdkVersion to "18" or lower, your alarms will continue behave as they have on previous versions when running on Android 4.4.

So, as you can see there, if you set the targetSDK to a previous API (before 19), it will behave as it use to, but if you target the newest API (at this moment API 19), then it will behave differently.

Hope i was clear enough, if not, please do not hesitate and ask.