# Compile error "Class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile my project in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). I'm using a class in an external JAR file and on compilation receiving the following error.

```
Class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
```

I understand that it's saying the JAR file was compiled with a newer Java version than that which IntelliJ is using. How do I make them compatible?

I have updated the Java on my Mac to 1.8 and when I run `java -version` or `javac -version` it confirms this.

What am I missing? (Apart from Java development experience)

Comment: You should check sdk configuration in your project(inside intelliJ) - maybe there you still are using old version - it depends on you configuration

Comment: Did you get the solution? In my case I switched to using java 7 and everything works.

Comment: "You are trying to run/reference a class compiled with JDK 8 using a runtime/compiler JRE/JDK 6."

Check the accepted answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906659/java-compiling-error-in-command-prompt-class-file-has-wrong-version-52-0-shoul

Comment: This is still an issue with intellij 2020.2 trying to switch from java 8 to java 14

Comment: I got this error when I was trying to run Spring boot 3.X on java 8. Spring Boot 3.X is compatible only with java 17 and above. Hope this finds someone in need.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Select "File" -> "Project Structure".

Under "Project Settings" select "Project"

From there you can select the "Project SDK".

Comment: If using Gradle, along with above settings, please also select appropriate Gradle JVM settings. For IntelliJ IDE, its under tab: "IntelliJ IDEA" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> Gradle, and update the Gradle JVM under "Gradle Projects"

Comment: wondering how this steps order answer the question as is just a matter of use another SDK and not really what the question asked

Comment: Or, if you can't change SDK like in my case, then lower maven dependency of the library causing this error.
I've had SDK 1.8_191, and I had to use TestNG 6.14.3, as versions 7.x caused this error

Answer (score 39):

If the error comes from an **external dependency** ([Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)/[Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle)), the version you imported requires a newer JDK. (*e.g., you imported [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) 3.0.x which requires [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11), but you are using [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).*)

Solution: downgrade the dependency to the latest version compatible with your JDK.

Java version numbers can be found in [Java class file wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) (byte offset 6-7).

Comment: Thanks! This explains why TestNG 7.6.0+ can't be used with Java 8. I downgraded the TestNG dependency to 7.5 and it worked.

Comment: I had a similar problem "class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0" for using the fundamental org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan class! For me changing the JDK/JRE version didn't solve the problem. Then I downgraded spring-webmvc dependency version from 6.0.2 to 5.2.6.RELEASE and it eventually worked.

Answer (score 33):

It means your Java runtime version is 1.6, but your compiler version ([javac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac)) is 1.8. To simply solve it, just advance your JVM version to 1.8.

But if you don't want to change the Java runtime version, then do the following steps:

1. `JAVA_HOME= "your JDK v1.8 folder path"`, to make sure JDK is also v1.8 and use `java -version` and `javac -version` again to ensure it
2. Make sure IntelliJ's compiler mode is set to compliant with v1.6. But I have tried that. It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: "it means your java runtime version is 1.8, but your compiler version (javac) is 1.6. To simply solve it, just retreat the java version from 1.8 to 1.6." - rather opposite

Comment: I corrected the answer according to the @KrzystofWolny's comment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692743/7769052

Comment: Re *"It didn't solve my problem."*: What is that supposed to mean? Why is it in an answer? Doesn't the last part of the answer work? Why is it included, then?

Answer (score 16):

Check the version of Java it is showing in the error:

- 45 = Java 1.1
- 46 = Java 1.2
- 47 = Java 1.3
- 48 = Java 1.4
- 49 = Java 5
- 50 = Java 6
- 51 = Java 7
- 52 = Java 8
- 53 = Java 9
- 54 = Java 10
- 55 = Java 11
- 56 = Java 12
- 57 = Java 13

Install/download that JDK in program files/Java folder.

In Eclipse or STS, right click on project → *Build Path* → *Libraries* → add JRE system libraries → add the version of JDK showing in the error as an alternate JRE.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Generally this kind of error happens when you try run a `.class` file which is compiled with another version of Java.

In your case, it is compiled with [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) (major version -> 52) and you want to run it with [Java 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) (major version -> 50).

Here is a list of major versions of Java and SE version:
[Class file format major versions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2)

To solve the problem, use the same version of the compiled class file, based on your project structure.
In IntelliJ IDEA: Menu *File* → *Project Structure* → *Project* → *Project SDK*

In case of using builder tools like [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), this configuration also should be changed in the corresponding settings. Here is an example of how it is done in a [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have got the same error as in the header because of a failed attempt to compile my project with [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and then reattempting to compile with [Java 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6).

Some classes where compiled at the first attempt with Java 8 and did not recompile with Java 6. Mixed classes did not compile then. Cleaning the project solved the problem.

This answer is not strictly relevant to the question, but it could be useful for someone.

Comment: Cleaning project did not do the job for me. I just removed the classes, which were throwing the error and did a clean build to get them compiled by 1.6. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am using **JDK 1.8.0_131** and For my case, the version code `<version>2.7.5</version>` in **pom.xml** and `module -> language level 8` solved my issue.

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `javac` to compile, and you get this error, then
remove all the `.class` files

```
rm *.class     # On Unix-based systems
```

and recompile.

```
javac fileName.java
```

Answer (score 1):

The error signifies that you may have the dependencies that are compiled in Java 11, but you are using Java 8, so there are two options left. You can either migrate to Java 11 or ask the library developer to provide you with a Java 8 build.

Comment: the versions you mentioned are wrong. It should be 8 (52.0) and 6 (50.0) instead of 11 (55.0) and 8.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. The issue may be because [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) and Java version are not compatible. For example, Spring Boot 3 need minimum JDK 17, so if you are using [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) then you have to downgrade your Spring Boot version to 2.*

*[Does Spring 3.0.x support Java 8? In Spring Starter I found sourceCompatibility = '17' default for 3.0.x and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983170/does-spring-3-0-x-support-java-8-in-spring-starter-i-found-sourcecompatibility)*

Comment: But for Spring boot 3, I have installed java 8 and its working fine in Eclipse without any problem but not in IntelliJ why?

Answer (score 0):

Class version 52 is [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). You need Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new JDK version, but I forgot to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the new JDK. Setting it to the correct version helped!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't change an SDK version, so I had to lower maven dependency of the library causing this error.
I've had SDK 1.8_191, and I had to use TestNG 6.14.3, as versions 7.x wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Project's [build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) file:

```
allprojects {    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            apiVersion = "1.8"
            languageVersion = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own JAR file, make sure that the application in which you are importing the JAR file has 'id' in the plugins section as 'application'.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}
```

If both JAR and application has 'id' as 'java', we might see a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Java 8 spring boot compactible version is 2.2.6.RELEASE

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

This nonsense still persists in 2024 in an IntelliJ kotlin project. I tried everything in the already given answers, but there's now a new way of getting the error:

Despite having everything set correctly in both "Project Structure" and "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Gradle" -> "Gradle JVM", my project *still* compiled to a newer java version than my target system could handle. The solution for me after hours upon hours?

Change your build.gradle.kts to use the correct toolchain, in my case

```kotlin
kotlin {
   jvmToolchain(17) // I can't run 18 atm.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the issue is in IntelliJ, then do this in the terminal (not in the IntelliJ terminal):

1. change the Java version to an appropriate one (in my case, using JDK 1.4 as the issue was `class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0`)
2. `java -Dspring.profiles.active=test -jar build/libs/<jarname>.jar` 
   Run this

Comment: can you be more specific about <jarfile> argument? If my error is ```bad class file: /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar!/javafx/application/Platform.class
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.``` then is the jarfile `graphics.jar`?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this by changing my [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F) file:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.6.4</version>
```

Change 3.0.2 to 2.6.4.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem, "Class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0" when running Java through [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant)...

All I did was adding **fork="true"** wherever I used the **javac** task, and it worked...

Comment: adding fork = true in configuration didn't work for me.

Answer (score -10):

In your IntelliJ IDEA, find file *tools.jar*. Replace it with *tools.jar* from your [JDK 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

Comment: Don't do this. The accepted answer is correct, and all kinds of weirdness could result from this alternative.