# Error:(3, 31) java: cannot access org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

so i got this error trying to use neo4j embedded:

```
Error:(3, 31) java: cannot access org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings
  bad class file: /C:/Users/stepa/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-configuration/4.0.2/neo4j-configuration-4.0.2.jar!/org/neo4j/configuration/GraphDatabaseSettings.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I tried to delete the file, re import, with maven, even downgrading the version of maven dependency. Has
 anyone encountered this behavior?
thanks for help :)

Comment: Upgrade to Java 11 (class version 55). Or downgrade from the latest neo4j to a version that still supports Java 8 (class version 52). Java 8 has been eol (from Oracle) for quite a while. The neo4j documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/#deployment-requirements-java) lists Java 11 as a requirement.

Comment: oh... well thanks, you saved me quite a lot of time, I totally forgot that could be an issue :Dd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180983/6821936 try this one

Answer (score 0):

It was the java version. By [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch); answered in the comments..