# java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication bad class file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, boot, sprint

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
  bad class file: /C:/Users/xyz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-3.0.0-20220910.145857-773.jar!/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.class
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Answer (score 19):

Change your springboot version to the previous stable version.

**Before** :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```

**After**:

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```

Answer (score 18):

### The reason is Spring Boot 3 requires java 17, as stated in [Preparing for Spring Boot 3.0](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0).

> class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0

Referring to [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers). and similar question [Class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180915/class-file-has-wrong-version-52-0-should-be-50-0)
It indicates that you are using java 8 but the class file is compiled for java 17.

Comment: Can we substitute this with an OpenJDK version?

Answer (score 8):

If you have java 8 installed on your machine and if you go to the spring initializer website and create an application by selecting Spring boot 3.0.0 (SNAPSHOT) and packaging as Jar and version as 8, then generated zip file will have version as 11 on pom even though you selected version as 8. which means, your local machine is having java version 8, and the generated zip file is having version 11 on the pom.

[image]

Comment: Don't use snapshot versions, because snapshot versions are currently being developed by the spring boot Team & you don't want to use them when creating a project. Use the released versions.

Comment: Here if you want to use spring boot 3 then select Java version 17

Answer (score 8):

I changed the version from **2.7.5 to 3.0.1** and it faced this issue.

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  bad class file
```

To resolve this issue, the **spring boot 3**  needs at least **Java 17** or a higher version of Java.

I also faced this issue because I was using **Java 11** so when i convert to **Java 17** in pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
```

and project structure of *project* and *modules* as well then the project worked perfectly

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with.

Happy coding! ‍

Comment: Perfectly working

Answer (score 4):

from 3.0.0 to 2.7.3 , I changed. then it went all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few solutions which may help you

1. Change Thymeleaf version from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Try changing your sdk in project structure

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
- Select **Project** under **Project Settings**
- Change your SDK to <kbd>**openjdk-17** Oracle OpenJDK Version 17.0.4</kbd> or <kbd>**openjdk-18** Oracle OpenJDK Version 18.0.2</kbd>
- If you don't have it, download it from Oracle site and press <kbd>Add SDK</kbd> button under **SDK:**
- Any SDK version above 17 will work
- Press <kbd>Apply</kbd> and press <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Right click anywhere on your pom.xml file and select <kbd>*Maven*</kbd>
- Then select <kbd>Reload project</kbd>
- Wait for the project to be reloaded
- Now Build your project and Run it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Spring Boot version from the *pom.xml* file.

I changed the version from ***3.0.0*** to ***2.0.2.RELEASE*** and it worked fine.

The problem occurs because Spring Boot version 3 requires Java version 17 to run whereas you are trying to run with Java version 8.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication bad class file: /C:/Users/homa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.3/spring-boot-3.1.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.class class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0 Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

when I changed version 11 to 17 my test was passed.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```