# Java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting this error when I try to start the Spring Boot Application:

**java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication   bad class file: /repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.1/spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.class**
*class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0*
*Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.*

I had a look at the below SO question and it looks like this error happens when the Spring Boot version is 3.0.1. But I dont have that version mentioned in the build.gradle file.

[java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication bad class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679679/java-cannot-access-org-springframework-boot-springapplication-bad-class-file)

here is the build.gradle file portion:

```
    springCloudVersion = '2021.0.3'
    springBootPluginVersion = '2.7.6'
    sonarQubePluginVersion = '3.3'
    gatlingPluginVersion = '3.8.4'
    nebulaPublishingPluginVersion = '18.4.0'
    nebulaReleasePluginVersion = '16.0.0'
    jasyptSpringBootStarterVersion = '3.0.4'
```

Using Java 11.

I can also see that every time I build the project in IntelliJ, a spring boot 3.0.1 jar and its folder are created under the repository mentioned above ( even if I delete it). I can't see where is that version coming from. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 need Java 17,  ( https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0 ) , `Upgrade to Java 17`

Comment: Yes, I know that... The project uses Java 11 and that's why I have springBootPluginVersion = '2.7.6'  in the build file.

Comment: Your Error Message is :`/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.1/spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!`

Comment: Try `gradle clean`

Comment: In IntelliJ, Gradle Tab, select your project , popmenu `Reload Gradle Project`

Comment: In IntelliJ, Gradle Tab, select your project , popup menu `Analyze Dependencies`, check your  Dependencies , spring boot version

Comment: springboot plugin version (like other plugins) cannot be set from properties inside the `build.gradle` file AFAIK. can you share your build script section where you actually apply the springboot plugin ?  something like ` plugins {   id  "org.springframework.boot" version "??????" }

Comment: I have tried 'gradle clean', reloading the project, and analyzing dependencies many times. At some point. one of them worked and I dont get that error anymore .. Thank you @life888888

Answer (score 0):

change the version as below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```