# Why cannot access Expression

Tags: java, android

I am getting the below error:

```
C:\Users\Think\AndroidStudioProjects\Calculator\app\src\main\java\com\lolodmc70\HomeActivity.java:84: error: cannot access Expression
                Expression exp = new Expression(userexp);
                ^
  bad class file: C:\Users\Think\AndroidStudioProjects\Calculator\app\libs\MathParser.org-mXparser.jar(/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Expression.class)
    class file has wrong version 62.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Here is the code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String userexp = operation.getText().toString();
                userexp.replaceAll("÷","/");
                userexp.replaceAll("×","*");

                Expression exp = new Expression(userexp);
                String result = String.valueOf(exp.calculate());

                operation.setText(result);
                operation.setSelection(result.length());

            }
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180915/class-file-has-wrong-version-52-0-should-be-50-0)

Answer (score 0):

The essential part of your error is

```
class file has wrong version 62.0, should be 55.0
```

So check the JDK and JRE versions you use to compile and run the project.