# Compatibility and migration from Java 9 to Java 8

Tags: java, java-9

I'm reading the [document](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/) about the new Java 9 module system.

The paragraph **3 Compatibility & migration** explains how to migrate code
from Java 8 to Java 9, but says nothing on how "migrate" or run an application
written in Java 9 to pre Java 9 runtimes.

So, if I have, say a JAR application written in a *modularity way* (every module has a module descriptor) what does happen if I deploy it on, i.e, a JDK 8 runtime?

Comment: If the compability was bidirectional, there wouldn't be need for Java 9

Comment: @xenteros Java 9 may be needed to augment the jar with module information (via `module-info.java`)

Comment: I don't know what will happen, but you probably know what happens when you try to run an application which is compiled with a newer major version of Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot start a Java application with a JRE which is less than the one it is built for.

If you just use `javac` without any special options it will produces classes which do run on JREs equal or bigger than the one of the used JDK.

However javac supports cross compilation. You can use JDK 8 to compile JDK 6 compatible class files. Search for *Cross-Compilation Options* in the [javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: That's not *universally* true. But it's a reasonable guideline.

Comment: And if I compile the application with a javac compiler targetted, i.e, for Java 8? After I use all the tools of a JDK8, i.e., jar for packaging that application? Maybe is the module descriptor simple ignored?

Comment: I can compile application written in Java 8 with Java 7 compiler if I didn't use any Java 8 features.

Answer (score 10):

If your class files are compiled with `--release 8` flag, then they should run fine on Java 8. `module-info.class` files will be ignored by the older JVMs.

If your Java 8 project is maven-based, you can easily configure it to include `module-info.java`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html

Also, take a look at [JEP 238](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) (Multi-Release JAR Files). This allows you to take even more advantages of Java 9 features without breaking compatibility with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Java Class files contain version information. As with any Java version it should not be possible to execute a class file (or jar) that was compiled with a newer major version than your runtime. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692743/6239524