# Why javac target option can not be lower than source option?

Tags: java, maven, javac

I have read about `source` and `target` options for `javac` that they define a version that my source code requires to compile and oldest JRE version i want to support, respectively. While using Maven build tool i have defined these parameters in pom.xml like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>15</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

, but target version can not be set lower than source version, why is it so?

Trying to compile with this configuration results in error: "Fatal error compiling: warning: source release 15 requires target release 15". Same with any other combination of source version being higher than target.

Comment: New language features often require support by the JVM to be implemented. A good example is that lambdas require `invokedynamic`. Therefore targeting a JVM version *earlier* than the one that got those features added would break: you'd produce bytecode that the target JVM can't interpret. There is a workaround, that's called "retrocompiling", but it's not offered by `javac` itself, but some third party tools can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that is how it is designed. From [the documentation of javac in Java SE 15 for the --target option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-target):

> **Note:** The target release must be equal to or higher than the source release. (See [--source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-source).)

I guess the usual is to have old source code that you want to run in newer releases and, when starting a project, you choose your source release as the oldest release that you want to support.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692743/2738151) for a discussion about backward and forward compatibility:

> In brief, we can say:
>
> - JDK's are (usually) forward compatible.
> - JRE's are (usually) backward compatible.

You can think about it as this: JDKs can compile (usually) for newer releases and JREs can run (usually) older releases.