# Using -target higher than -source with javac

Tags: java, performance, compilation

I've got a project written using `JDK 1.4.1` an `JDK 1.7` installed on my machine. I can build those *1.4-sources* with the line:

```
javac @sources.txt -source 1.4 -target 1.4 -deprecation -classpath %cp% -Xstdout log.txt -d .\classes
```

Is it possible to run it with `-source 1.4 -target 1.7` combination?

---

Also I'm curious will there be any performace gain if I run application written with JDK 1.4.1 on the system where JDK 1.7.1 is installed?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663450/whats-the-difference-between-source-and-target-compatibility ?

Comment: Ok, so I can use `-source 1.4 -target 1.7`. Will this work faster on JDK 7 than on JDK 1.4?

Comment: Depends on your source code, I guess ;-) I don't think so, however, there are other reasons why one wouldn't want to do that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983310/jdk-jre-an-jars-compatibility

Comment: I'm appreciated for your useful input. Form it as a question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however, I don't think you are winning performance by doing so. Furthermore there are reasons why you do NOT want to do this, see [JDK, JRE an JARs compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983310/jdk-jre-an-jars-compatibility)

Comment: *String concatenation* would be a reason to target a newer Java version. With `-target 1.4`, it uses `StringBuffer` under the hood, which performs unnecessary synchronization. With `-target 1.5` or higher, including `-target 1.7`, it will use `StringBuilder` which does not perform synchronization.