# Can Android apps use java 8 compiled jars?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I create a java library independent of the Android framework. Classes/methods in this java library have been written with **Java 8** streams and lambdas. I then compile my java library into a jar and add it as a dependency in my Android project.

Can my android app use that jar even though Android itself only supports Java 7?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: No, I don't think forward-compatibility works like that. Java's jre7 does not know about the jre8 standard libraries.

Comment: I just found this stack overflow post, which explains why differences in Java 7 vs 8 bytecode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm

Comment: Android doesn't have streams in its library, even if you did make lambdas work somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Do you explicitly need Java 8 *compiled* JARs? Otherwise you can use a retro-compiler.

I plan to use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) to integrate Java 8 code into my Android project.