# Can I use Dagger 2 with Java 7?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

It seems all Dagger 2 and Dagger Compiler 2 jars are compiled with Java 8.

So the question: Is it possible to use Dagger 2 with Java 7?

I keep getting this error:

```
dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentProcessor : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Which simply translates to a Java 8 compilation incompatible with Java 7.

Comment: Since Dagger 2 is supposed to be used in Android application then it should work with Java 7.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm

Comment: Version 52 is java 8... seems wierd they compiled it like that.