# GeneXus 15 + Google Cloud Deployment Error: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, genexus, genexus-sd

I have seen many answers in these forum, but none related to GX so far, and the ones I've tried haven't solved this issue.

When trying to deploy a GX 15 + JAVA + Web + Mobile I get the following error:

```
...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: C:\modelos\pruebagoogle\Deploy\JavaModel\GAE\20170422042109\WEB-INF\classes\com\proyecto02\gamcheckuseractivationmethod.class
Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: C:\modelos\pruebagoogle\Deploy\JavaModel\GAE\20170422042109\WEB-INF\classes\com\proyecto02\gamcheckuseractivationmethod.class

error: C:\GeneXus\GeneXus15\DeploymentTargets\GoogleAppEngine\deploy.msbuild(4,3): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\android\engine\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.51\bin\appcfg.cmd" -A proyecto02 update "C:\modelos\pruebagoogle\Deploy\JavaModel\GAE\20170422042109" -V 3" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project "C:\GeneXus\GeneXus15\DeploymentTargets\GoogleAppEngine\deploy.msbuild" (Deploy target(s)) -- FAILED.
...
```

To build mobile apps GX 15 requires JDK 8.

Has anyone been able to deploy to Google Cloud?
Any suggestions to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

GeneXus Java generator does not require Java 8, [it requires Java 6 or higher](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30900), Genexus Android generator [requires Java 8](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14449).

Each generator has independent properties to set the JDK to be used, compiler options, etc. So, no matter you are using JDK 8 you are able to set "Java compiler options" (for Java Generator) as: -O -source 1.7 -target 1.7 in order to compile the application to run on 1.7 JVM (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm))

Another solution is to have both JDKs installed, to set JDK 1.7 path as Java Generator/Compiler path and JDK 1.8 path as Android/Compiler Path.

Comment: Greetings Gustavo! Thanks again for the answer.
I finished a Rebuild All and tried with both JDKs installed and setting each separately for Java and Android, and it didn't work.
The other way, setting the options **-O -source 1.7 -target 1.7** in the **Build Process - Advanced - Compiler Options** and doing another Rebuild All didn't work neither.
I will have to check all the rest of the configurations, something else must be missing.

Comment: I still get no way out of the same error.
I am working with **jdk1.7.0_80** and **jdk1.8.0_131**, which versions are you working with?
By the way, my app has GAM.