# Java source 1.8 and Target 1.6 is it possible in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a java application coded in java 8, but we are using weblogic container that supports only java 1.6, can you please let me know if there is any way I can compile my source in Java 8 and force it to compatible with java 1.6 using maven as like source to 1.8 and target to 1.6?

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I doubt it Java 8 code would be transcompiled to 6 as bytecode. Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

No, and this is a limitation of javac itself, it has nothing to do with maven.

There are some options for attempting to use j1.8 features and then compile it down to j1.6/j1.7 JVMs, see [Can Java 8 code be compiled to run on Java 7 JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm)

However, note that JDK8 is about to end-of-life, and JDK6/7 are looong gone. You really should address that instead. Your container is at serious risk of having security issues (in that JDK6 and 7 no longer receive security patches).

Answer (score 0):

You can run Java 6 applications on Java 8,
BUT Java 8 features are not available on Java 6.

JVM says no. ;)